# Pandas: check column values by ignoring cases (convert cases)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, uppercase

I am trying to check values of a pandas column using the following condition:

```
my_df[my_df.name.str.contains('MY_TARGET')]
```

This works fine. But since I need to convert the name column to upper case, I did the following but didn't work:

```
my_df[my_df.name.str.upper.contains('MY_TARGET')]
```

What's the proper way to perform the column value checks by ignoring cases? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use `case = False` parameter ie.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['my_target', 'foo', 'bar', 'My_TarGet']}) #Coldspeed data
df[df['name'].str.contains('my_target', case=False)]
```

Output :

```
       name
0  my_target
3  My_TarGet
```

Comment: Didn't know about a `case` param.. nice. +1

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use the method chain like below. `.uppper()` as method(parenthesis) and additional `.str` accessor for the following `.contains()` method.

```
my_df[my_df.name.str.upper().str.contains('MY_TARGET')]
```

Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['a'])
print(df[df[0].str.upper().str.contains('A')])

   0
0  a
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Convert to upper case using `df.apply(str.upper)`

```
In [1283]: my_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['my_target', 'foo', 'bar', 'My_TarGet']})

In [1279]: my_df[my_df.name.apply(str.upper).str.contains('MY_TARGET')]
Out[1279]: 
        name
0  my_target
3  My_TarGet
```

For this case, you can specify `regex=False` for an additional speedup.

---

**Option 2**

Use the regex flag `re.I` (ignore case) with `df.str.contains` (`import re` first)

```
In [1282]: my_df[my_df.name.str.contains('MY_TARGET', flags=re.I)]
Out[1282]: 
        name
0  my_target
3  My_TarGet
```